# json photo path xcode

Tags: objective-c, json

i can't get my photo in json, did i haven't something wrong to get that? i already check my photo url in php,it works,

in my tableview.m file:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailHomeViewController * dvc = [[DetailHomeViewController alloc]init];

    HomeDetail * currentHome = [HomeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    dvc.photodetail = currentHome.photo_path;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:dvc.photodetail];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    dvc.photolabel.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    [self presentViewController:dvc  animated:YES completion:nil];
}


#pragma mark - Methods
- (void) retrieveData
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    HomeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (int i = 0; i < json.count; i++)
    {

        NSString * photo = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"photo_path"];


        HomeDetail * home2 = [[HomeDetail alloc]initWithPhoto_path:photo];

        [HomeArray addObject:home2];
    }

    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}
```

my HomeDetail.h file:(Json file)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * photo_path;

//Methods
- (id) initWithPhoto_path: (NSString *) photo ;
```

my HomeDetail.m file:

```
- (id) initWithPhoto_path: (NSString *) photo ;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {photo_path = photo;}  
    return self;
}
```

my DetailHomeViewController.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * photodetail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photolabel;
```

my DetailHomeViewController.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

   // photolabel.image = photodetail;


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:photodetail];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    photolabel.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

and here is my json data:

```
[{"id":"2","detail_english":" TESTING_DETAIL","photo_path":"img\/uploads\/news\/news_20150320075842.png","date":"2013-10-15"‌​,"display_stat":"1","news_order":"1"},
{"id":"5","detail_english":"empty","photo_path":"img\/uploads\/news\/news_20150323105547.png","date":"2015-03-20","display_stat":"1","news_order":"1"}]
```

Comment: Can I have a correct answer,cause I read apple development documents already,but I still dont know what wrong I got~

Comment: What does this have to do with the `xcode IDE`?

Comment: Where is you JSON Data?

Comment: My JSON FILE in HomeDetail.h&.m file

Comment: I was asking more for the json data so we can have a look at the json itself. If you could provide that then that would be great

Comment: this is one of my json file photo

Comment: What? Sorry but why have you shared an image with us? We want to see the json data not an image.

Comment: like this?
[{"id":"2","detail_english":" TESTING_DETAILTESTING_DETAILTESTING_DETAILTESTING_DETAILTESTING_DETAIL ","photo_path":"img\/uploads\/news\/news_20150320075842.png","date":"2013-10-15","display_stat":"1","news_order":"1"}]

Comment: Yeah that's what we want to see. Please can you add it your actual question so others don't have to read through some comments to find it. Thanks

Comment: added~hope someone can solve my problem,thanks

Comment: Can you `NSLog` `photo` after this line `NSString * photo = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"photo_path"];` and tell us what it is?

Comment: i go this two:when i used NSLog:

"2015-03-27 23:04:09.952 HKFA[12453:241393] img/uploads/news/news_20150320075842.png

2015-03-27 23:04:09.953 HKFA[12453:241393] img/uploads/news/news_20150323105547.png"

Comment: Like `meda` has said your photo url isn't a full URL. How will your app know where to look for it?

Comment: So this is my JSON file problem,not my code problem?

Comment: Yeah by the looks of it. You're not returning a full URL only part of the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your photo path is not a full url, you need to append the domain name.

So you string would look like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/img/uploads/news/news_20150323105547.png
```

Comment: the photo is in my database file,so my json file should not have a domain name,it didn't correct?

Comment: @MatchTsui if you dont put the domain how would your app know how to find it on the server

Comment: i try to append the domain name in my url,it works,that mean i need to change my photo link in json file?